# Как перенести Ubuntu из под виртуалки в Windows в отдельную систему?

Tags: windows, ubuntu

У меня стоит Ubuntu из под винды, но в винде теперь нет необходимости, при этом все данные которые сейчас есть необходимо оставить в целости и сохранности(те которые на убунте), собственно вопрос как лучше всего поступить в этом случае?

Или выход только 1 - сносить все и ставить "с чистого винта"?

---

Еще мысль была - если тупо форматнуть диск с виндой ubuntu запустится? И если да - будет ли нормально функционировать?

Comment: Ubuntu на виртуалке?

Comment: Счастливый Вы - "но в винде теперь нет необходимости"

Comment: @mikillskeggпо поводу счастливый - это да :)<br>
<br>
@culebre - да...

Comment: В виртуалке сам ubuntu на отдельном разделе ?

Comment: Да ubuntu в виртуалке ставилась с винды и да - на разных разделах

Comment: Хм на самом деле возможно виртуальный образ перелить, но все зависит от вируталки, не все позволяют, хотя здесь я могу ошибаться, вроде xen позволял, но у вас точно, не он. Гемора будет много по любому танцы с Grub2, драйвера, насколько помню, udev автоматом каждый раз заново перепроверяет, но все это если конечно есть желание сливать всю систему и получить н-ое количество экспы=). А если нет, будет проще и быстрее с чистого винта.

Comment: Можно попробовать просто установить grub (загрузчик) куда-нибудь на сменный носитель (например флопик) загрузится с него и попробывать загрузить дальше ununtu - если получится ставить grub в MBR

Comment: Во во дискотека на всю ночь)) В линуксе нет ничего невозможного.

Comment: Вы мне напишите - сама ОС останется жива после того как я снесу диск C?<br> Если да то установка дров и т.п. - не является проблемой( я на таких тостерах ubuntu ставил что не будем баловаться, но с такой задачей сталкиваюсь впервые )<br>
Тогда прийдется до завтра отложить, где я дискету то возьму? xD

Comment: А что за виртуалка? Grub, кстати, можно поднять на livecd Ubuntu.

Comment: всмысле? ну virtualBox, в простонародии коробка...<br>
Вообщем не суть, сношу диск C и пусть будет что будет ^^<br>
Вообще интересно получается - винда у меня сейчас как паразит какой-то...<br>
Флешка с livecd в наличии...<br><br>
Та не конфигурация то фигня... Самое главное я уже записал на болванку...

Comment: Проверить все можно из установочного CD с ubuntu, и с него-же можно и GRUB установить. GRUИ можно не только на флопик ставить, но и на флешку (HOWTO соответствующий можно найти в инете)

Comment: Если нужно сохранить только данные, то заливайте их в Ubuntu One. А если надо и конфигурацию сохранить, то конечно можно примонтировать образ жд, но как это будет ли это работать стабильно - не очень понятно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть варианты с переносом папки **home**... Я долго пытался (убунта тоже была установлена из под wubi) - почти вышло
Общий план таков:

1. сделать резерную копию всего что надо (я предполагаю это все файл диска виртуального)
2. снести Windows и Ubuntu и поставить новую Ubuntu
3. Наполнить новую убунту системными файлами

но это морока жуткая - если не столько уж много настроек - проще заново сделать - я так и сделал =)

Comment: Спасибо но уже поздно, мой комп начал жизнь с чистого винта ^^<br>
Вообще конечно ubuntu с virtualBox и то что сейчас - земля и небо...<br>
это я к тому что советую тем у кого есть возможность ставить бубнту как самостоятельную ОС а не из коробки..

Answer (score 0):

Ничего нет проще. Сначала делаете stage4 своей nix* системы, переносите её на какой-то внешний носитель (например flash-накопитель), например так: http://gentoo-wiki.gentoo.ru/wiki/Stage4 ;

Затем инсталлируете grub на машину с windows (Куча материала в google);

Наконец разворачиваете nix* систему из stage4, добавляете запись в свой загрузчик и пользуетесь. Таким способом Вы сохраните и win* систему и *nix .